# UI not updating buttons when using Task.Factory.StartNew in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

WPF/XAML/C# I set visibility of progress bar to visible, then hidden after a long running process.  I am trying to use Task.Factory.StartNew and ContinueWith to accomplish this.  This part works fine, but for some reaso, my navigation buttons that are databound to commands do not update until i actually click the screen following the long process.  if i omit the task.factory.startnew, the buttons update correctly (but i never see the progress bar).  how do i fix this?  Here's sample code showing problem with the process and buttons not updating in the UI:

```
private void DoWorkCommandExecuted()
        {
            //Do stuff
            ShowProgress = Visibility.Visible;

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    //Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                    {
                        s += i.ToString();
                    }

                    ObservableCollection<string> temp = new ObservableCollection<string>();
                    temp.Add("One");
                    temp.Add("Two");
                    temp.Add("Three");
                    temp.Add("Four");
                    temp.Add("Five");

                    BillingCycles = temp;

                    SelectedBillingCycle = BillingCycles[0];
                })
                .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                ShowProgress = Visibility.Hidden;
            });
        }
```

And a sample of one the property the buttons code that controls it enabled :

```
private bool CanFirst
        {
            get
            {
                bool b = false;

                if (BillingCycles != null)
                {
                    if (BillingCycles.Count > 0 && SelectedBillingCycle != BillingCycles[BillingCycles.Count - 1])
                    {
                        b = true;
                    }
                }

                return b;
            }
        }
```

I am using INotifyPropertyChanged.  This is a very basic example illustrating my problem, which is in a much more complex program.  The "Go to first" or "Go to last" buttons should enable/disable based on what BillingCycle is selected.  If i do not include the code to run in thread, the buttons are enabled/disabled correctly (i just can't see the progress bar while the process happens).

Comment: Are you notifying that CanFirst has changed after you change SelectedBillingCycle?

Comment: it continually checks that boolean since its part of the relay command, like canExecute.  Like i said, it works fine if i don't use any threading

Comment: Are you relying on the CommandManager to run your canExecute function? Or are you raising the CanExecuteChanged event?

Comment: I am using RelayCommand, so it like this:  FirstCommand = new RelayCommand(() => FirstCommandExecuted(), () => CanFirst);  the CanFirst part of the lambda has it check if the method can be executed

Comment: ...and i put a break point in the getter of CanFirst that only breaks when true, and that happens, it just doesn't update the button on UI for some reason.  until i click anywhere in the window, then it updates

Comment: i also tried putting this in where it sets the BillingCycle, but to no avail:   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                                {
                                    SelectedBillingCycle = BillingCycles[0];
                                }), DispatcherPriority.Render, null);
                    
                })

Comment: Does the RelayCommand you're using have a way to manually raise the CanExecuteChanged event? Try calling that in the Action instead of setting SelectedBillingCycle. (or calling `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`)

Comment: Like i said, if I don't use Task.Factory.StartNew, it works fine.  RelayCommand is therefore not the issue, since it works when don't use threading.  Somehow i am not updating the UI thread correctly i guess...

Comment: new RelayCommand(() => FirstCommandExecuted(), () => CanFirst); ... That second lambda statement is the CanExecute function for your command. It's evaluated when the CommandManager figures it should do so, or when you raise the CanExecuteChanged event on the command.

Comment: I put in FirstCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged() in the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and it seems to work.  The question is:  why doesn't it work without that?  This seems kinda hackish, and i need to put this all over the place and for more than just FirstCommand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason it wasn't working for you is the CommandManager was calling your command CanExecute method while on a background thread and was unable to update the button from there. Calling command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged() on the UI thread after the operation is complete causes the system to re-evalute while on the UI thread, so the button update works.

Comment: thank you for helping.  i would still like to know how to properly get this to work, it seems like this shouldn't be so goofy

Comment: I like to avoid using the CommandManager for this reason. When you raise the CanExecuteChanged events yourself you have more control over when and where it does the re-evaluation and you aren't left guessing and hoping that the CommandManager does the correct thing.

Comment: why does CanFirst.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); also update the buttons for CanPrev, CanNext and CanLast?  They are navigation buttons, i did not call RaiseCanExecuteChanged on them , only CanFirst, but they all then update.  Again, thanks for your help, I'm trying to learn about WPF and threading

Comment: I see many answers that say CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() is the way to go.  In my case, i had to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke around it to get it to work.  So RandomEngy, would you say this is acceptable?  Do you prefer your explicitly calling RaiseCanExecuteChanged or InvalidateRequerySuggested ?  Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that something you're doing during the first RaiseCanExecuteChanged is causing the CommandManager to refresh the state on all the other buttons. Much like how you said any interaction with the UI caused the buttons to update. As for my preference, I like using the RelayCommand in MVVM Light and avoiding the CommandManager, I find that things work much more predictably then. Though it is still "acceptable" to use the CommandManager.

Oh and mark this answer as accepted if you think it's been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth to check in which thread you are updating notify property, it should be indispatcher thread.
If not - set the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged and binding should be two way or one way. Please let me know if works

Comment: i cannot set updatesourcetrigger as it is the CanExecute property that is not being updated correctly, causing the buttons to not update their IsEnabled status.  As RandomEngy said, it appears CanExecuteChanged is being raised on the background thread...